# Invoke specific controller instead of requesting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have developped an mvc plugin system, in which plugins loaded on `PreApplicationInit` event. Plugin configurator have an ability to disable plugin load on next startup. Almost everything is fine except that when I try to navigate to disabled plugins controller/action IIS tells me that resource is not found (and that's normally)

All plugins and their states are availiable through static `Dictionary<IPluginInfo, bool>` where boolean variable is a state of plugin and which is initialized in `PreApplicationInit`.

The question is, can I redirect to some predefined page (controller/action) in case of trying to address a not-loaded plugin's controller/action instead of getting the 'resource not found' error page?

Comment: Look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417%28v=vs.140%29.aspx It is possible to define error handlers. Also one for 404. This should work.

Comment: Okay! That's the possible solution. But, what to do if i want to show custom page about disabled plugin only for that cases? For other 404 errors it is normal to show IIS 404 page

Comment: You can use a a controller action that returns based on your specific problem

Comment: Yeah! Done everything in this way! Thank for hint)

Comment: I would add this as an answer for future reference. It would be nice if you could accept it then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure a 404 error page in web.config. The url can be a path to another controller so you can decide what to do in the action method